# Rethrow an Exception with correct line numbers in the stack trace

Tags: c#, .net, throw

You are apparently able to rethrow an Exception without discarding the stack trace in .NET.

However it doesn't appear to be working.

Basic usage I'm following is thus:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void ExceptionTest()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("An Error Happened");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            evlWebServiceLog.WriteEntry(ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Problem is, the line number in the exception in the line of the `throw;` line, not the original `throw new` line.

I've tested it in a simple exe project and without the logging to the windows log line. It doesn't make any difference, the stack trace always has the wrong line number in it, making it less than useful.

Why is it doing this?
How do I do it correctly?

Comment: That does not lose the stack trace. What makes you think that it does? Are you not logging or displaying `ex.ToString()`?

Comment: Is the line number in the ´CallStack` of the ´InnerException´ correct?

Comment: Are you sure you are using `throw` and not `throw ex`? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/730250/11683 for inspiration.

Comment: @ROBOJ, I do not agree with you, How about wrapping inner exception if you are so desperate?

Comment: apparently its a limitation - if a method has more than one throw you get the last line number - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493779/wrong-line-number-on-stack-trace

Comment: Sorry, I muddled up "losing stack trace" with "wrong line number". This question was indeed answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493779/wrong-line-number-on-stack-trace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not lose original exception if you place it in an inner exception.

```
[WebMethod]
public void ExceptionTest()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("An Error Happened");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        evlWebServiceLog.WriteEntry(ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        throw new Exception("Your message", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: But you loose original exception type (though in your example both original and rethrown exceptions are of Exception type). ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex).Throw() throws exception of original exception type.

Answer (score 6):

I've used the following for years. Don't know if there a less "dodgy" way to achieve it in more up to date .Net frameworks though:

```
public void PreserveStackTrace(Exception ex)
{
    MethodInfo preserve = ex.GetType().GetMethod("InternalPreserveStackTrace",
                                                 BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    preserve.Invoke(ex,null);
}
```

To use this:

```
[WebMethod]
public void ExceptionTest()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("An Error Happened");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        evlWebServiceLog.WriteEntry(ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        PreserveStackTrace(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

**Update**: based on @dcastro's comment, I'd fancy an extension method in 4.5 (in < 4.5 it could still be an extension wrapping the method above):

```
public static void ReThrow(this Exception ex)
{
    var exInfo = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex); 
    exInfo.Throw();
}
```

So you'd just have:

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        evlWebServiceLog.WriteEntry(ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        ex.ReThrow();
    }
```

Comment: Nowadays you can use `var exInfo = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex); exInfo.Throw();`

Comment: @dcastro: Nice - I see that's appeared in .Net 4.5

Comment: ReThrow() is a great idea, but unlike "throw e;" it now gives an error saying "not all code paths return a value" - any idea how to fix properly?