# How to cast generic action delegate to concrete action delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, .net-4.6

I am implementing a subscription-based reading of messages from IBM MQ websphere and I am using `IBM.XMS.dll` which has an event-based mechanization. Following is my code for subscription:

`T` is the type of data accepted by the callback function `onMessageReceived`. I will have to parse the message body from `IMessage`, convert to type T and invoke `onMessageReceived` from`OnMQMessageCallback`

```
    public override void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> onMessageReceived)
    {
        try
        {
            MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener(OnMQMessageCallback);
            _consumer.MessageListener = messageListener;

            _connection.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private void OnMQMessageCallback(IMessage msg)
    {
        try
        {
            //I want to invoke onMessageReceived in this method
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

From `OnMQMessageCallback`, I want to invoke `onMessageReceived()` which is passed into the `Subscribe()` method from the caller. I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: Just to make sure, in your actual code, you do something else than catch/throw, right? Like custom logging or something? Otherwise, you should think about removing that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218781/is-there-a-benefit-to-just-a-throw-in-a-catch/218929

Comment: What is `T`? how would you call `onMessageReceived` if you had a reference to it? `T` is only known at the scope of the `Subscribe` method.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten T is the type of data accepted by the callback function onMessageReceived. I wil have to parse the message body from IMessage, convert to type T and invoke onMessageReceived

Comment: It's not. It's `IMessage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using [anonymous delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx)

```
   MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener((m) =>         
    try
    {
        onMessageReceived();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    });`
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it uses *closure* for a reference on `onMessageReceived`

Comment: `onMessageReceived` is `Action<T>` Where is `T`?

Comment: This could be a little clearer but I think this is the answer. You take `m`, you convert it to `T` and then you pass the result of this conversion into `onMessageReceived`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to call the `onMessageReceived` if it's defined a `Action<T>` out side the scope of `Subscribe`. You simply don't know what `T` is.

Either you do this and let the caller handle the parsing later:

```
public override void Subscribe(Action<IMessage> onMessageReceived)
{
    MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener(onMessageReceived);
    _consumer.MessageListener = messageListener;

    _connection.Start();
}
```

Or you parse it yourself (don't know how) and call it:

```
public override void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> onMessageReceived)
{
    MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener((m) =>         
    {
        T result = (T) m.Body; // or some other casting
        onMessageReceived(result);
    });`

    _consumer.MessageListener = messageListener;

    _connection.Start();
}
```

No need for `OnMQMessageCallback` anymore.

Side Note: There's no point in `try..catch..throw` it's the same as not doing a `try..catch` at all.